# express.js route not recognizing null value for conditional response

Tags: node.js, express, ecmascript-6

I am trying to render an alternative response to my express.js route when a date value in the parameter ends up being invalid.  When I see an invalid date the value ends up being null so in my if statement in the middleware I test for a truthy value and if it is not truthy i serve up an alternative response.

What I get is the true value even though the value of the date is null.  Here is an example:

api/timestamp/hello is my route.

A valid date should look like this: `{"unix":1546214400000,"utc":"Mon, 31 Dec 2018 00:00:00 GMT"}`

An invalid date like 'hello' should look like this `{'error': 'Invalid Date'}`

The code returns the correct value if the date is valid, but if the date is invalid I get `{"unix":null,"utc":"Invalid Date"}` instead of `{'error': 'Invalid Date'}`

Below is the code.

```
   app.get('/api/timestamp/:date', (req,res) => {
    let date = new Date(req.params.date);

    if (date === null) {        
        res.send({'error': 'Invalid Date'});             
    } else {
       let unix = date.getTime();  
       let utc = date.toUTCString();
       res.send({unix, utc});  
    }  
});
```

I'm relatively new to express and Node.js for that matter. Any thoughts on why the null value is not being recognized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q: Wouldn't it make sense to check for a valid date *BEFORE* you try converting it to Unix and UTC?

```
app.get('/api/timestamp/:date', (req,res) => {

  let date = new Date(req.params.date);
  if (req.params.date && date instanceOf Date) {
    let unix = date.getTime();  
    let utc = date.toUTCString();
    res.send({unix, utc}); 
  } else {
    res.send({'error': 'Invalid Date'});
  }
}
```

Comment: Sure that does make sense to me.  I went ahead and did that.  I do need to declare the date variable outside the if statement because req.params.date would still return a true value, but if I pass it through the Date method that's when I see the null value.  I'm still getting the same response even though I convert the date to unix & utc.

Comment: OK - you can check for both "date != null" and "date is valid".  I've updated the example.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are building your response, node thinks it's a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), therefore you get the strange response.

To get what you want you can make something like this:

```
app.get('/api/timestamp/:date?', (req,res) => {
  if(req.params.date){
    let date = new Date(req.params.date);
    let unix = date.getTime();  
    let utc = date.toUTCString();
    if(unix) return res.send({unix,utc})
    res.send({'error': 'Invalid Date'});
  } else 
    res.send({'error': 'Invalid Date'});
})
```

Comment: I didn't even think about it being read as a destructuring assignment.  That would make a lot of sense.  I should clarify more on this problem.  If req.params.date is null then I want to use the current timestamp, if it is invalid, then I want to serve the error JSON response, if it is valid I want to serve that current timestamp.

Comment: hi, so if it's a valid date, you want to return something like {date:1546368889275}? i'll edit my answer accordingly

Comment: Thank you.  So if it's a valid date I want it to return {"unix":1451001600000,"utc":"Fri, 25 Dec 2015 00:00:00 GMT"}.  If it's an invalid date, I want it to return {'error': 'Invalid Date'}.  If there is no date in the param, I'd like it to return the current timestamp, which I can currently do by just declaring a route for /api/timestamp/.

Comment: hi, fixed the answer again. in resume you check if uni is NaN, if not you can use the res.send({unix,utc}) idiom with no concerns.

Comment: Thanks this definitely worked!  Now I need to figure out how to get it to recognize unix dates :).

Answer (score 0):

Date constructor returns date to 1 January 1970 if the parameter is null and I can't think of any case it would return `null`.

Which means that your first check will always be false since your are using strict equality.

Probably you better be checking if `req.params.date is truthy` and `unix` is a valid timestamp

Hope this helps